# animation not running perfectly on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i m making a game in which animation is running perfectly on iphone simulator but when i run on the device it crawls.I m using NStimer to repeat the function in which animation is running.NSTimer repeats after 0.4 sec and animation duration is also 0.4.It is running perfectly on simulator but on device when animation duration completes there is some gap between next animation start .Some blinking has been shown.If anyone has a solution pleae help me s

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference in the amount memory available to the simulator and the actual device.

You need to perform some performance optimizations. But without some sample code, we won't be able to help you.